# How many $3 \times 3$ non-symmetric and non-singular matrices $A$ are there such that $A^{T}=A^2-I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How many $3 \times 3$ non-symmetric and non-singular matrices $A$ are there such that $A^{T}=A^2-I$?

Note: $I$ denotes the identity matrix of size $3 \times3$ and $A^{T}$ represents the transpose of the matrix $A$.

I took transpose on both sides in given equation to get $A=(A^T)^2-I$ and then I put value of $A^T$ in this equation using $A^{T}=A^2-I$ to get $A^3-2A-I=0$ which ultimately gave $(A^T-A)(A+I)=0$ . How to deal the problem from here? And is there any better approach to tackle this problem? The given answer is $0$.

Comment: Well, don't you have your answer? From your matrix equation you get the fact that the only matrices satisfying this equation are either symmetric matrices or $-I$, so no non-symmetric matrices exist which satisfy the matrix equation

Comment: @junkquill The product of two matrices is 0 doesn't imply that one matrix is zero.

Comment: Ah! My bad, completely slipped my mind

Comment: Did you get this from the GRE? Sounds familiar

Comment: If you follow your recipe you should get $A^4-2A^2-A=0$. How did you justify "dividing by $A$"?

Comment: Because $A$ is nonsingular

Comment: Ah, I missed the non-singular condition.

Comment: Which is the base field? $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb F_{2017}$ or...?!

Comment: @dan_fulea In this context that's a pretty pedantic question, it is apparent that it's either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ and the answer doesn't depend on which.

Comment: $A=-I$ doesn't verify the solution... And neither a large class of symmetric matrices

Comment: That doesn't imply anything, if there are no non-symmetric matrices satisfying this equation, doesn't mean that every symmetric equation satisfies it. For example, A = $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ does. But you're right, a large class of symmetric matrices doesn't satisfy the equation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $$(A^T - A)(A + I)=0$$

Since $A$ is nonsingular, $\det A \neq 0 \implies \det A^T \neq 0 \implies \det (A^2 - I) \neq 0 \implies \det(A+I)\cdot\det(A-I)\neq 0$ $$\implies \det(A+I) \neq 0 \neq \det(A-I)$$

Therefore, $$(A^T - A)(A + I)=0 \implies A^T - A = 0$$
And we're done

---

Here's something else that I noticed. You arrive at the following equation:
$$A^3 - 2A - I=0 \implies A^3 - A = A+I \implies A(A^2 - I) = A+I \implies AA^T = A +I \\ \implies A = AA^T - I$$
Therefore, $A$ *is* symmetric

Comment: If $A=I$ then $\det(A^T-A)=0$.

Comment: $A = I$ doesn't satisfy the original matrix equation, so that case will never arise

Answer (score 4):

I would like to say why the above dan_fulea's comment is good and Ian's comment (upvoted!) is inappropriate and also why it is assumed that $A$ is invertible. Note also that the hypothesis $n=3$ has nothing to do here. Assume that $A\in M_n(K)$.

Case 1. $K=\mathbb{R}$. Since $AA^T=A^TA$, $A$ is normal and therefore unitarily diagonalizable; then we may assume that $A=diag(\lambda_i),A^T=diag(\overline{\lambda_i})$ where $\overline{\lambda_i}=\lambda_i^2-1$. The previous equation has only real solutions and, consequently, $A=A^T$. Note that the hypothesis "$A$ invertible" is useless.

Case 2. $K=\mathbb{C}$. Note that $A(A+I)(A^2-A-I)=0$ and $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$.

If $\det(A)\not= 0$, then $A(A^2-I)$ is invertible and consequently $A(A+I)$ too; we deduce easily that $A^2-A-I=0$ and $A=A^T$.

Assume that $\det(A)=0$ and $A$ non-symmetric; then $0,0^2-1=-1\in spectrum(A)$ and $A^2-A-I\not= 0$.

For $n=2$ a solution is $A_2=1/2\begin{pmatrix}-1&-i\\i&-1\end{pmatrix}$ where $spectrum(A_2)=\{0,-1\}$.

For $n=3$, a solution is  $A_3=diag(A_2,(1+\sqrt{5})/2)$  where $spectrum(A_3)=\{0,-1,(1+\sqrt{5})/2\}$.

Comment: For $K=\mathbb{R}$, correct me if I'm wrong, if $A$ wasn't invertible, then there would be at least one $\lambda_i=0$ and then it wouldn't satisfy the original matrix equation. So I'm guessing, it's useful

Comment: @junkquill , Yes, when $K=\mathbb{R}$, all the solutions (necessarily symmetric) are invertible.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is very good: $A=(A^T)^2-I$, so
$$
A=(A^2-I)^2-I
$$
which becomes $A=A^4-2A^2+I-I$ and, owing to $A$ nonsingular, $A^3-2A-I=0$. This can be rewritten as $A(A^2-I)-(A+I)=0$ or $(A+I)(A^2-A-I)=0$, hence $(A+I)(A^T-A)=0$.

You have to exclude that $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, so ensuring $A+I$ is invertible, which would lead to $A^T=A$.

If $Av=-v$, with $v\ne0$, then $A^Tv=A^2v-v=0$. This is not possible because $A^T$ is nonsingular. The assumption the matrices are $3\times3$ is not required.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A^3-2A-I=0$ , any eigenvalue of $A$ satisfies
$$\lambda^3-2\lambda-1=0 \Rightarrow \lambda=-1, \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Let $\lambda_{1,2,3}$ be the eigenvalues of $A$. Then 
$$tr(A^T)=tr(A^2-I) \Rightarrow
\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3 = \lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2+\lambda_3^2-3 \\
\Rightarrow \sum_{j=1}^3(\lambda_j^2 -\lambda_j -1) =0 \qquad (*)$$

Note that $\lambda= \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$ satisfy $\lambda^2 -\lambda-1=0$, while $\lambda=-1$ satisfies $\lambda^2 -\lambda-1>0$

It follows from $(*)$ that $-1$ is NOT an eigenvalue of $A$.

Therefore, the minimal polynomial of $A$ is 
$$\mu_A(x)=(x- \frac{1 +\sqrt{5}}{2})^\alpha (x- \frac{1 -\sqrt{5}}{2})^\beta$$

Moreover, since $A^3-2A-I=0$ we have $\mu_A(x) | X^3-2X-1$ and hence $\alpha, \beta \leq 1$.

Therefore, we have three choices left:
$$\mu_A(x)=(x- \frac{1 +\sqrt{5}}{2})\\
\mu_A(x)= (x- \frac{1 -\sqrt{5}}{2})\\
\mu_A(x)=(x- \frac{1 +\sqrt{5}}{2}) (x- \frac{1 -\sqrt{5}}{2})$$

The first two lead to the solutions
$$A=\lambda I \qquad \lambda= \frac{1 \pm +\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
While the last gives
$$A^2-A-I =0$$
and hence 
$$A=A^T$$